# How to delete restriction group

Tags: acumatica

What is the proper way to delete a restriction group??  Yes we can deactivate the group.  But I noticed there is no delete button.  Is this by design?  I prefer not to hack the Db.

Answer (score 2):

Restriction Groups can't be deleted and must be made inactive. We don't recommend trying to delete them yourselves; the GroupMask field of all the records affected by this group depends on the entries and won't be updated correctly. This feature is on our roadmap but no ETA is available at the moment.